# ¿Cuándo decir ''[verbo] a [complemento]''?

Tags: gramática

Sé que tengo que añadir a veces una *a* entre el verbo y el complemento. ¿Cuándo tengo que añadir la *a*?

Ejemplo: Ella llama a Juan.

Nota: Español no es mi idioma nativo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ESPAÑOL (English follows)**

Has de añadir "a" tras el verbo cuando le sigue un complemento directo.
Para saber si estamos ante un complemento directo, prueba a preguntar de la siguiente forma:
*Ella llama a Juan.*
*¿A quién llama ella?*
*He comprado un libro.*
*¿Qué he comprado?*

Como regla general:

- Cuando sigue un nombre propio: *Ella llama a Juan*.
- Cuando sigue un nombre común o colectivo relacionado con personas, con artículo determinado o pronombre demostrativo o posesivo: *Ella llama a sus hijos. Ella llama a esas personas. ¡Llama a ese! Ella llama a las compañeras de clase. Ella ha llamado a su equipo para que vengan pronto.*

No has de añadir "a" cuando sigue un nombre común o colectivo relacionado con personas con artículo indeterminado o pronombre demostrativo o posesivo, o un nombre relacionado con cosas: *Regalé mis libros. Quiero un coche. Crucé el Mediterráneo.*

Puedes consultar más detalles en el [Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=ctMgM8Bp2D6ELPuNfg)

---

**ENGLISH**

You have to add "a" after the verb when it is followed by a direct object.
To find out if this is a direct object, try asking as follows:
*Ella llama a Juan.*
*¿A quién llama ella?*
*He comprado un libro.*
*¿Qué he comprado?*

As a general rule:

- When it is followed by a proper name: *Ella llama a Juan.*
- When it is followed by a common or collective name regarding people with a definite article or demonstrative or possessive pronoun: *Ella llama a sus hijos. Ella llama a esas personas. ¡Llama a ese! Ella llama a las compañeras de clase. Ella ha llamado a su equipo para que vengan pronto.*

You must not add "a" when follows a common or collective name related to people with indefinite article or demonstrative or possessive pronoun, or a name related to things: *Regalé mis libros. Quiero un coche. Crucé el Mediterráneo.*

You can check more details in the [Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=ctMgM8Bp2D6ELPuNfg)

---

Comment: Por tanto, ¿solo cuando el complemento directo refiere a una(s) persona(s)? / So, only when the direct complement refers to a person/people?

Comment: @Archa Es una regla general, pero tiene excepciones (por ejemplo cuando se personifica una cosa). Mira el enlace para ver más detalles. It is a general rule but has exceptions (eg when a thing is personified). Look at the link to see more details.